# How to spawn a child process for the main process from another Python script?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

I would like to separate the following code into two python scripts. One in charge of updating `myVar`. The other one receives the updated `myVar`.

```
import multiprocessing

def func(myVar):
    myVar = 2


if __name__ == "__main__":

      myVar = multiprocessing.Value('d',2) #update myVar from the child process

      p = multiprocessing.Process(target = func, args = (myVar,))

      p.start()
      p.join()

      print(myVar) #get the updated myVar
```

Desired structure would be:
**update_myVar.py**

```
def func(myVar):
    myVar = 2


#if __name__ == "__main__": #spawn child process for main.py's main()

      myVar = multiprocessing.Value('d',2) #update myVar from the child process

      p = multiprocessing.Process(target = func, args = (myVar,))

      p.start()
      p.join()
```

and **main.py**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(myVar)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why? How often? You can use a memory mapped file and write the variable there, then read it from the other process. Have a look at the `mmap`.

Comment: Since I have 2 separate running scripts. They would like to share data with each other while both are running. I would not prefer mmap since that associates to file system which will slow down the whole data transmission speed. One will have to write the file first and the other one will have to read from the file.

Comment: Well, a memory mapped file is not slow, since it is all in memory. That is, no disk access is needed to fetch the data. One way or another you will need to access a common memory area. But, still, it depends on how often and how much data you need to pass between the scripts. And I still wonder why you have two different scripts accessing the same variable.